# I am trying to fetch the contact Detail using the AWS SDK ( amazon connect ) . I am unable to get full detail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I need to find all the contact detail of my contact Id. The API I am using is not generating me all the details of the contact ID .

Is there any other API that I should use?

```js
AWS.config.update({
  region: region,
  accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey:secretAccessKey
});

const connect = new AWS.Connect();
const params = {
  InstanceId: InstanceId,
  ContactId: ContactId
};

const getContactSearchHistory = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await connect.describeContact(params).promise();
  }
}
```

With the above code, my expectations were to fetch all the details like  Contact ID, Channel, Initiation timestamp, System phone number, Queue, Agent, Customer phone number, Disconnect timestamp, and Contact duration.

But right now I am only getting these values using this API:

```json
{
  "Contact" : {
    "Arn" : "**",
    "Id" : "***",
    "InitiationMethod" : "OUTBOUND",
    "Channel" : "VOICE",
    "AgentInfo" : {
      "Id" : "**",
      "ConnectedToAgentTimestamp" : "***"
    },
    "InitiationTimestamp" : "**",
    "DisconnectTimestamp" : "**",
    "LastUpdateTimestamp" : "**"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify the version of the AWS SDK you are using, it's possible you're not getting the correct information because the version you have is not up to date. For Lambda, you can find the NodeJS runtimes and SDK versions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html)... they do get updated frequently but usually is not pointing to the latest version. I would create a virtual environment locally, get the newest version of the SDK and run the same API call and verify you're getting the correct information that's reflected in the docs.